# ehrenamtlich vs. freiwillig

Tags: meaning, difference, adjective

In my German class, we recently discussed the concept of "*ehrenamtlich"/"Das Ehrenamt - der Kitt der Gesellschaft*".  In the discussion, it was made clear that *ehrenamtlich* relates to honorary posts and roles, while *freiwillig* relates more to voluntary.

Reading the textbook however, it seems that people are involved in activities in the community, associations etc., which to me is more *freiwillig*. It would be correct to use *ehrenamtlich*, if one was chosen to lead or have an official role (without pay) in the club/association.

Can someone please clarify how I should view the difference and whether there is any difference in meaning with Austrian German?

Comment: @SatishVasan _Ehrenamtlich_ implies freiwillig, while _freiwillig_ doesn't imply to take a specific position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ehrenamtlich* implies more responsibility, as it includes *'amt'*, meaning *'appointment'* or *'duty'*. You are right about the assumption that an Ehrenamt often includes being selected or voted for an important (yet unpaid) position.

*Freiwillig* is a much more broad term. Look at this sentence, for example:
"Wir wollten Ihn rauswerfen, aber er ist **freiwillig gegangen**"
-> "We were going to kick him out, but he left on his own."

Even though *ehrenamtlich* and *freiwillig* sound like synonyms, ehrenamtlich would be very wrong in this context.

**Ehrenamtlich usually means freiwillig, but not the other way around.**

To answer your question about helping out in the community: As a rule of thumb, If you engage in a long-term commitment, have responsibilities or are appointed/voted in, *Ehrenamt* is probably the way to go. If you are "just helping out" with, for example, a one-time event or manual labor, *freiwillig* is more fitting.

Comment: Man kann sich bestimmt für jede Definition oder Erklärung einen absurden Sonderfall ausdenken, um diese auszuhebeln. Es gab bestimmt schon einmal jemanden, der zum Ehrenamt gezwungen wurde, da hast du recht. @userunknown

Comment: Ein weniger konstruiertes Beispiel (Nachtrag: als das im gerade eben gelöschten Kommentar) von nicht-freiwilligem Ehrenamt kann das Schöffenamt (ehrenamtlicher Richter) sein. Es wird zwar immer erst nach Freiwilligen für die jeweilige Amtsperiode (meist 5 Jahre) gesucht, aber wenn sich nicht genügend Freiwillige finden, werden auch Personen nach dem Zufallsprinzip aus dem Melderegister ausgewählt und zwangsverpflichtet.

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich ein gutes Beispiel für so einen Fall. Habe meine Antwort auch bearbeitet. @VolkerLandgraf

Comment: @lukasgabriel - The reference to long-term vs short-term commitment was very helpful.  Matter of fact, in the article - "Trotz der beeindruckenden Zahlen ist in der öffentlichen Diskussion von einer Krise im Ehrenamt die Rede.  Das liegt am Strukturwandel, den der Freiwilligendienst durchliebt. So engagierten sich die Menschen früher langfristig in Vereinen, Parteien oder der Kirche und blieben den Organisationen über Jahre hinweg treu. Heute ist das oft anders. Besonders jüngere Menschen setzen sich gern für Projekte ein, die zeitlich und inhaltlich begrenzt sind, z.B. Bäume pflanzen...

Answer (score 5):

*Ehrenamtlich* and *freiwillig* often refer to the same thing, but the focus is different.

*Ehrenamtlich* (from *Ehre* = *honor* and *Amt* = *position*, *office*) means that someone does a job without being paid. So s/he does it for honor only, not for payment. *Honorary* is probably the most accurate translation.

*Freiwillig* means that someone volunteered to do a job. So this can be translated by *voluntary*. But this adjective is also used as a translation for *ehrenamtlich* which is probably the reason for your confusion.

Comment: Would you consider upvoting questions that you thought of being well enough to answer?

Answer (score 3):

The problem the question is based on is the fact that words have different meanings depending on the context. Taken by itself, *freiwillig* will be interpreted as *voluntary*, i.e. indicating that someone is acting under their own free will.

> Du isst freiwillig Hafergrütze?

However, in the context of volunteer work, *freiwillig* and *ehrenamtlich* are often used synonymously, indicating work that is performed for free (or at least, not for financial gain) and for the benefit of the public. Some examples where *freiwillig* is used for *ehrenamtliche Tätigkeiten*:

- Freiwilliges Engagement, Freiwilligenarbeit (["Allgemeine Erklärung zum freiwilligen Engagement"](https://www.bmfsfj.de/blob/100620/c9fff914094c43297a7b7689a4e63f2a/allg-erklaerung-zum-freiwilligen-engagement-data.pdf))
- [Freiwilligendienst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiwilligendienst)
- [Freiwilliges Soziales Jahr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiwilliges_Soziales_Jahr)
- [Bundesfreiwilligendienst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesfreiwilligendienst)

The umbrella term would be [bürgerschaftliches Engagement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrgerschaftliches_Engagement).

Comment: Getreidespeisen haben ganz ungerechtfertigterweise einen schlechten Ruf. Gegen Haferbrei ist überhaupt nichts einzuwenden. Genausowenig gegen Graupen, die ja bei Pippi Langstrumpf als so verabscheuenswert dargestellt werden. Eine sehr leckere Mahlzeit ist das in Süddeutschland traditionelle "Schwarze Mus" aus langsam geröstetem Weizen- oder Dinkelschrot.